# Shopify Dashing Widget

Tags: ruby, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dashing

I am using shopify dashing for couple of our projects. Just wanted to check whether is there a possibility to use blueocean pipeline stages inside the widget? I have checked for the possibility but unfortunately I haven't find any clue. Just wanted to check if others are any having any inputs regarding the same.

**I am referring to the below screenshot:**
[image: Blue_Ocean_Pipeline_Stages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite as useful as what you're looking for, but the closest you're probably going to get is the [Embeddable Build Status Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/embeddable-build-status) which shows you the overall status of the whole build, something like this:

[image: build status plugin icon showing a failing build]

From the job's classic (not Blue Ocean) view, follow the "Embeddable Build Status" link, which takes you to a page that provides the link in several formats (plain link, Markdown, HTML, etc).

You'll need to take some permissions into consideration: *protected* links require the user to have `Read` permission to the job; *unprotected* require `ViewStatus`.

Links are provided for *With View* and *Without View*, where the former includes the "view" used to navigate to the job and the latter does not.

**Caveats**:

- Using the *Without View* link doesn't seem to work for multibranch pipeline jobs as of writing (Jenkins 2.121.2; build status plugin 1.9): it genereates a link like:

  ```
  http://JENKINS_HOME/job/MultiBranchJobName/BranchName/badge/icon
  ```

  but it needs to be modified to treat the branch as a job, like:

  ```
  http://JENKINS_HOME/job/MultiBranchJobName/job/BranchName/badge/icon
  ```
- If your branch name has a `/`, it looks like only the *(with view) protected* links escape it properly, where the `/` becomes `%252F`. Other links use `%2F` and need to be manually adjusted to `%252F`.